# dovecot: Is it possible to remove a user?

Tags: ubuntu, email, email-server, dovecot

If I do `doveadm user '*'` I see many users, including my server's username, docker user, and so on.

I want to keep all those users, I just don't want them to be dovecot users, I only want to have one dovecot user,  which I use to receive emails. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, Dovecot can do anything from reading /etc/passwd-like files all the way to sql or ldap, whatever you need (`userdb` and `passdb` are the chapters you need to read to figure which is suitable for your environment)

Answer (score 0):

You may not have to do anything. Check your `first_valid_uid` and `last_valid_uid` settings - it limits which of the users you have configure in your user database are actually valid Dovecot users.

For logging in and mail delivery, these settings work the way you want: You can keep your system users, and keep Dovecot configured for reading the system user database (`passwd`), yet only have *some* of them also be Dovecot users.

However, the `doveadm` tools unfortunately mostly ignore this, as partly documented in the man pages:

> If the **-A** option is present, the command will be performed for  all  users. Using this option in combination with system users from **userdb { driver = passwd }** is not recommended, because it  contains  also  users  with  a  lower  UID  than  the  one configured with the `first_valid_uid` setting.